# Unable to update CosmosDB via LogicApps

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

I am unsure as to why I am constantly facing the following errors when trying to use Logic Apps to update a document in CosmosDB:

1. PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header
2. One of the specified inputs is invalid

For error 1, I sent the following request via LogicApps:

```json
{
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
        "x-ms-documentdb-is-upsert": "True",
        "x-ms-documentdb-raw-partitionkey": "12347"
    },
    "path": "/dbs/bc-gamification-management/colls/bcpoints/docs",
    "host": {
        "connection": {
            "name": <omitted as this shouldn't matter>
        }
    },
    "body": {
        "curr_point": 500,
        "id": "12347",
        "overall_point": 1400
    }
}
```

Not too sure where I got this idea but for error 2, I omitted the partition key from the body request:

```json
{
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
        "x-ms-documentdb-is-upsert": "True",
        "x-ms-documentdb-raw-partitionkey": "12347"
    },
    "path": "/dbs/bc-gamification-management/colls/bcpoints/docs",
    "host": {
        "connection": {
            "name": <omitted as this shouldn't matter>
        }
    },
    "body": {
        "curr_point": 500,
        "overall_point": 1400
    }
}
```

I have tried troubleshooting this using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-bad-request and various other methods like, using "id" and "/id" in the **Partition key value** instead of the actual value of the partition key. But all these methods did not work and I am not too sure why...

FYI, the CosmosDB has items with the following sample:

```json
{
    "id": "12347",
    "overall_point": 1200,
    "curr_point": 300,
    "_rid": <omitted as this shouldn't matter>,
    "_self": <omitted as this shouldn't matter>,
    "_etag": <omitted as this shouldn't matter>,
    "_attachments": <omitted as this shouldn't matter>,
    "_ts": <omitted as this shouldn't matter>
}
```

The "id" field is also the Partition Key for the Collection. Please advice :")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is something like this

```
{
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
        "x-ms-documentdb-is-upsert": "True",
        "x-ms-documentdb-raw-partitionkey": "\"12347\""
    },
    "path": "/dbs/testdb/colls/testcoll/docs",
    "host": {
        "connection": {
            "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    },
    "body": {
        "curr_point": 500,
        "id": "12347",
        "overall_point": 1400
    }
}
```

You need to put your partition key within quotes, like this.

[image]